# Display all properties of a Class with XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am new to WPF and spent hours of searching a solution for that, but I cannot find anything.

I want to display all properties of a class with a `DataTemplate`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Car}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

```
public class Car
{
    public int Axes { get; set; }
    public int Seats { get; set; }
    public int Doors { get; set; }
    public VehicleProperties.Car.Type Type { get; set; }
    public int MaxWeight { get; set; }
    public Fuel Fuel { get; set; }
    public double ConsumptionPer100km { get; set; }
    public bool Childseat { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int FirstRegistration { get; set; }
    public int Mileage { get; set; }
    public Transmission Transmission { get; set; }
    public int Power { get; set; }
    public bool Tempomat { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Color { get; set; }
    public int PollutionClass { get; set; }
    public int EnvironmentalBadge { get; set; }
}
```

How can I at least display the name and bind the `ItemsSource` and the `TextBlock` correctly? I need that, because after this, I will design the `DataTemplate`s with the `DataType` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only interested in the property names of a concrete type, you could create a custom markup extension that receives a type and uses reflection to get its property infos and returns the property names as enumerable.

```
public class PropertyNamesExtension : MarkupExtension
{
   public Type Type { get; set; }

   public PropertyNamesExtension(Type type)
   {
      Type = type;
   }

   public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   {
      return Type?.GetProperties().Select(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.Name);
   }
}
```

In XAML you can use the markup extension with the type `Car` as `ItemsSource`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{local:PropertyNamesExtension local:Car}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

If you want more information, e.g. the type of each property, return the [`PropertyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo?view=net-5.0)s instead.

```
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
   return Type?.GetProperties();
}
```

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{local:PropertyNamesExtension local:Car}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding PropertyType, Mode=OneWay}"/>
         </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

---

> I need that, because after this, I will design the DataTemplates with the DataType-Property.

I do not know exactly what you goal is, but I think you are trying to achieve something different. Let's suppose you want to display a single **instance** of a `Car`. Then expose that instance through a property and bind it as `Content` of a `ContentControl` with a `DataTemplate`.

```
public Car Car { get; }
```

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Car}">
   <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}">
         <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Brand}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Axes}"/>
            <!-- ...other markup. -->
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

If you want to show a list of `Car`s, expose them as any collection, e.g. a `List<Car>` or an `ObservableCollection<Car>` if the collection is changed at runtime (otherwise added or removed items will not be updated in the user interface). Then use an `ItemsControl` or `ListBox` or `ListView` depending on your requirements and add an `ItemsTemplate`.

```
public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars { get; }
```

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Brand}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Axes}"/>
            <!-- ...other markup. -->
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I have to develop a program where you can create vehicles, but there are different types of vehicles (there are cars, motorcycles, trucks...) and different properties. Because of this, I created for each vehicle a class with the required properties and I am programming now the dialog for creating a new vehicle. That means, for string, I need a TextBlock with the name of the property but for bools or custom classes, I need a ComboBox with the properties of the class. So I need different DataTemplates for a dynamic creation of the creation dialog.

Comment: @Alive318 Then you can use the single `Car` instance example with a `ContentControl`. Just add a `DataTemplate` for each different type of car specifying the respective `DataType`. You can put the markup for each of the properties in that template, no need for creating a separate data template for each simple property. For complex properties - let us assume `Transmission` - you could use the same approach within the `DataTemplate`. Add a `ContentControl`, bind the `Transmission` porperty and supply a `DataTemplate` for that type in scope.

Answer (score -1):

C# code

```
Car car = new();
itemControl.ItemsSource = car.GetType().GetProperties();
```

Comment: That would be a solution, but I work after the MVVM-Concepts and because of this, I cannot use this.